# Android facebook key hash

Tags: android, sign

after spending hours of figuring out how to sign an app (at last i used eclipse, and not the command line), i want to create a key hash to my app described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android_key_hash).
For this i have in the C:\Users\Family\workspace\MyKeys folder the created sample.keystore and the samplesigned.apk, as well as the keytool.exe and the jli.dll.

In cmd.exe i navigated to C:\Users\Family\workspace\MyKeys and when i run this command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias samplekey -keystore sample.keystore` i get this jibberish:[image]
The samplekey is the alias of the key created in eclipse:

[image]

I download open ssl from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) and installed it into C:\Program Files\GnuWin32. Navigating here in the command line i tried this command: openssl -help, which resulted in a list of commands which means i installed it properly (i hope).

Now i try this code:

```
C:\Users\Family\workspace\MyKeys>keytool -exportcert -alias samplekey -keystore sample.keystore | c:\program files\gnuwin32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | c:\program f
iles\gnuwin32\bin\openssl base64
```

Error: *'c:\program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

I have also added C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin to the PATH in Environmental Variables.

I'm kind of lost.

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app/17732453#17732453

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the paths in your command else it'll break on first space (i.e. 
`C:\Users\Family\workspace\MyKeys>keytool -exportcert -alias samplekey -keystore sample.keystore | "c:\program files\gnuwin32\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "c:\program f
iles\gnuwin32\bin\openssl" base64`).

Unsure if that is the real problem, but try it.