# Error while generating keyhash in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to generate key hash for Facebook. I have installed openssl and also registered my app on Facebook. For generating the key hash, I'm using following command.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\User\.android\debug.keystore|C:\OpenSSL\bin shal -binary|openssl base64
```

Which is giving me this response:

```
'C:\OpenSSL\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What does the error message mean and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: i've created a tool for that, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605
 up vote my answer if i helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to install openSSL. Just unzip and store it in C drive.Make a copy of your debug.keystore and store it in another drive. Say D drive. Try this

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\NewFolder\debug.keystore"|"C:\OpenSSL\openssl--0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl" shal1 -binary"|"C:\OpenSSL\openssl--0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl" base64

Ensure your change your OPENSSL version. Mine was 0.9.8 yours might be different

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install openSSL from:
http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

In my case OpenSSL was not installed properly due to some dependencies and I faced the same issue.
Solution: Find the directory in which openSSL is extracted (in my case -- C:\OpenSSL-Win64)

and use the command with absolute path to openSSL

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\nnagella\.android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl base64
```

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the first command for the error message is:

```
|C:\OpenSSL\bin shal -binary|openssl base64
```

The first `|` means the output of the previous command (which may also have problems) should be fed to `C:\OpenSSL\bin`, but the shell is complaining that `C:\OpenSSL\bin` is not an executable - it is most likely a directory.

Maybe that should read:

```
| C:\OpenSSL\bin\sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64
```

Your first command segment may also have problems:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool -exportcert ...
```

That `>` should probably be a backslash:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\keytool -exportcert ...
```