# Can't authorize if a phone has Facebook app for Android.

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [key hash for android-facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

I'm trying to fix the error about Facebook and I found that it can't authorize if a phone has Facebook app.

It works very well before, and also when a phone has not Facebook app. 
It might be because the recent update of the app..??

Here's error msg below. It says invalid_key.

```
09-09 14:07:11.520: D/Facebook(30618): ::: onFacebookError :::
09-09 14:07:11.520: E/Facebook(30618): invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "ig/T0MmkPGxn5mWnZCKub2mIHr0" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your app's signature on your app's Facebook dashboard.

Go to step 5 of this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) on our documentation and follow the instructions.  You need to put this text "ig/T0MmkPGxn5mWnZCKub2mIHr0" (without the quotes), in the Android Key Hash section of your app's dashboard.