# Facebook Android-sdk Key Hash

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an Android application using Facebook Integration for SSO, I have tested the application and it is just working fine on emulator, now when I test it on real device (Samsung Galaxy S3) I get "Facebook error" invalid key RuUnRoM+ySb9AWKHAb5slfvneeh.

I read other answers on similar questions here on SO saying that add that key to app settings on facebook and it should work but it is not working for me, any suggestions?

Moreover I am not sure form where did this key came from, the one I generated using the application's key store and keytool is lW2TM46BWUoKczD3t/ohbjx8v0A=.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Solved it by using

C:\Users\Me>keytool -exportcert -alias my_key -keystore my.keystore -storepass PASSWORD > mycert.bin

C:\Users\Me>openssl sha1 -binary mycert.bin > sha1.bin

C:\Users\Me>openssl base64 -in sha1.bin -out base64.txt

Source: [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564008/595603)