# White blank screen on using facebook android sso

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am implementing facebook Android SSO in my app. It works fine with the devices not having facebook app installed. However, with a device with fb app installed,  blank screen appears after the progress dialog.
 [image: facebook sso white screen]

The app login never appears as shown here on facebook android guide. ([https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/AndroidSSO_basicperm.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app))
I am using the same code from fb guide as a demo. I have generated the keyhash as shown there. Please help.

---

EDIT: I generated a new keyhash after signing it with new keystore using eclipse. With that keyhash it is working fine which means that there is a problem with the keyhash generated from android debug. I was generating the debug keyhash as answered here ([Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)). But sso is not working.

Comment: does it works now??I am also facing similiar issues..

Comment: No it's not working in debugging mode. It is only working with the signed version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, there's a bug with using SSO on a phone that already has the Facebook app installed. Although it's claimed to be fixed, I've had several issues with this aswell. For me, forcing the login dialog works:

```
fb.authorize(*YourActivity*.this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {
```

Also, you could save the access token and expires token in sharedPreferences to prevent user from having to log in every time.

If this doesn't work, please post the code you're using.

Comment: I am using the code from facebook android guide. And the FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH works for me too. But I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use password 'android' when creating the hash