# Facebook Keyhash issues

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

I have recently installed the facebook 3.0 sdk, all the applications run and all the classes link but they do not pull back any information from facebook. I have run the keytool command on cmd promt and retrieved my keyhash with the password: *android*. This has then been put into my facebook developer settings.

I have tried retrieving my keyhash on multiple situations and it returns the same code so I know it is correct. This is the error that appears in LogCat on eclipse when it accesses logging on:

`com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id " another is "W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(30221): Failed to send`

Has anyone else had any issues like this or have any recomentations?

Cheers,
Oli

Comment: See answers and comments to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app

Comment: Hi Gunnar, i have already done this and used the correct openssl from google

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#troubleshooting and try out the tips.

Comment: check my solution here, just drag and drop the keystore file  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605