# Facebook authorization issue with SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have an app for my University and there i have integrated Facebook SDK so that students can post in Facebook.

Recently i decided to make some more tests because of the new SDK that Facebook released. What i found it was that after the Custom Dialog by Facebook Sdk that appears and gives the user infos about the permissions needed, nothing happens.

That pushed me to search the problem deeper. I opened an Emulator and checked it too, after some errors and minutes i managed to make the SSO work. The same code was supposed to work on my device also, but again the problem described above was happening.

Although i had no luck with it. Then it came to my mind to delete the Facebook app from my Phone and try my app again. The SSO worked fine as in the emulator this time.

So i got stucked with a problem and a result after searching. I am completely sure that there is a problem between the authorization when having the Facebook app installed and my app, but i cant find what.

If anyone else has experienced the same problem please share your thoughts and if anyone knows any solution i would be greatfull!

P.S.: Google didn't help me at all. You are my last chance.

My way to connect with Facebook:

```
Session session = Session.openActiveSession(act, true,
            new StatusCallback() {
                public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        Log.d("Session is:", " opened");
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        if (user != null) {
//my code goes here                                         

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

I finally solved by updating the keyhash. Dont know why was that the problem but now it works fine!

Comment: debug and release(device) are different. u shud include both the keys in ur fb dashboard

Comment: Can you explain a little more your comment?

Comment: the keyhashes for testing on emulator and on real device are different. One does not work for the other. U need to generate 2 keyhashes, one for each and update the same to FB dashboard under the same app

Comment: the problem though is that it wont work...i tried it on an emulator and worked fine, then tried it on my device worked fine too, after that tried it on my brother's and cousin's device and had no luck...so i am wonderin if this is really a bug....

Comment: Any ideas guys what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of mention, use this code to find ACTUAL keyhash:

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.myname.lolo", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           //String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            * String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
           Log.e("hash key", something);
} 
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
}

catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
}
catch (Exception e){
Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

You can delete this code afterwards. And all the credits to this: [Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)