# Session Provided to a request in unopened state

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook friend picker sample in the Facebook SDK 3.0 shows error dialoge box. 
the message box says:
'com.facebook.Facebook Exception : Session Provided to a request in unopened state.'

Comment: Did you modify the sample at all? Is this reproducible always? What are your repro steps?

Comment: no i did not modify the sample. i think it is hash key error as it works perfectly in the emulater but shows error on device.

Comment: I had the same error when I forgot to perform all steps from Facebook-android-sdk installation guide. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ . I didn't notice that step 4 is so long.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error, if you are running this from Eclipse then there is a good chance there is a more detailed error in the log cat. For me I found the real error was that my Android hashkey did not match up with the hashkey I had provided to Facebook.

Double check that the hashkey you are using is correct. See this Answer for setting up your hashkey

[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Further, using the Keytool did not help me for my HashKey, instead I followed the advice on this guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

In step 4, see Troubleshooting, and modify the code to output your HashKey and use that one instead. The hashkey I had generated from Keytool was much different than this one. After that recompile everything, it should work fine.

Comment: Its Working in the emulator so it might be because my Hashkey provided is wrong. I did the above steps and got the same hash key provided. Is there any way to know if the hash key i got was correct??

Comment: You know your hashkey is correct if Facebook accepts it when you log in, otherwise something is a miss. Are you signing into the same facebook account as the one you have set up as a developer? Have you tried running the code solution on both the emulator, and the physical device to see if theres a hash key discrepancy? If the code solution and the keytool solution are both giving identical hash keys and you have provided that key to facebook, everything should be fine. If not, tell us what Error you are getting in your Logcat. Cheers.

Comment: @billgates Do you still have this problem? If this was not the answer, then I'd like to know what was.

Comment: i was using 64bit windows. when I changed it to 32 bit it worked fine.