# android facebook login with webview

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, webview

I have an android app where I'm using Facebook login. My problem is this: if I install the application from ADT everything works well, I am able to login via Facebook app and via webview, but if I download the app from Playstore I'm not able to login via Facebook app (though I can login via webview if I uninstall the Facebook app).

Now, I would like to know if is possible to force the login via webview even if the Facebook app is installed. Or how to make it work both ways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

if u r using `Facebook LoginButton` for login, then u can use web dialog for login. do this:

```
LoginButton login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
login.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Answer (score 4):

(I tried this code, FacebookSDK version 4.5)
Force WebView Login with custom login button :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY)
```

also, you can below

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_ONLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Single-Sign on and then you will only have the webview login.

But why would you do that? the SSO is much easier for your users.

In order for the SSO to work, you will need to configure your facebook app with the key you used to sign the Android app in the Play Store. see for example [Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)