# How to get Default Facebook app login session in to our application in Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to make Facebook login from my application and I am done that successfully. But I want, if Facebook default application in my device and I already logged in then it will automatically login in to my application.

I am not able to understand how can I get the default Facebook login session. If anyone has any idea then please share with me. Is there any way to get Facebook information with device information ?

I am stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

I used with this code: AM I ON RIGHT WAY? or Need to use other code? Please suggest me..

```
private void signInWithFacebook() {

        SessionTracker mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(getBaseContext(), new StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            }
        }, null, false);

        String applicationId = getResources().getString(R.string.applicationId);
        mCurrentSession = mSessionTracker.getSession();

        if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
            mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
            Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            mCurrentSession = session;
        }

        if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
            Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
            openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this);

            if (openRequest != null) {
                openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
                openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "email"));
                openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

                mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
            }
        }else {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject());
                }
            });
        }
    }






public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

But every time I got session.isOpen() = false. How can I solve this please help me. I am stuck on this.

Comment: Can you give us some piece of code here. It will be easy for us to see the prm.

Comment: @anddev: see my this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406153/android-facebook-login-with-webview/15420063?noredirect=1#15420063
here i have described how to login without FB default app. you have to just change the `SUPPRESS_SSO` to `SSO`. for your notice, i have worked with FB SDK a long time ago. but if u have any question, you can ask. :)

Comment: Please DO NOT use SessionTracker directly. As you can see, it belongs to the com.facebook.internal package, and is not meant to be consumed as a public API. As such, it can change at any time, and backwards compatibility is not guaranteed. You should be able to do everything you need with only the Session class.