# signed apk file can not login with facebook SDk3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I finished my application and every thing works fine but after i signed my app to publish it on google play the signed apk can not login with facebook and i tried below methods to solve this issue but nothing works at me till now.

1. I generated the hashkey by keytool and added it to my application page on facebook.

   ```
   keytool -exportcert -alias kartag -keystore C:\Data\app\client\android\keyStore\KarTag | "C:\bin\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\bin\bin\openssl" base64
   ```

   then entered android as password and entered my keystore password also but nothing works.
2. I wrote below code to got  the hashkey at runtime and the generated key is different  from generated by above method and added also in my facebook application page but i does not work too.

   ```
   String key = "";
   try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
               "com.kartag.gui", 
               PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
           key = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
           }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

   }
   ```

Please if you know any method to solve this issue help as i spent three days untill now to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the key hash you submitted to facebook corresponds to the keystore you used to sign the application submitted to google play? if it was working before signing it, you most likely have your debug keystore hash submitted to facebook, instead of your signing keystore hash.

Comment: i signed the apk by eclipse so the keystore after generation i executed the above command by keytool. are you see any thing wrong?

Comment: Yes, "android" password is usually the default password for the debug keystore. If you generated your own keystore you would tipically use a more secure password. Have you "Exported" your app within eclipse or just "ran it"?  Not really sure about your java code though.

Comment: i tried my keystore password which i entered in sign process by eclipse but does not work also. i exported the app by eclipse as mentioned in this link at section "Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT" 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Where did you get your version of openssl from? Sometimes (especially on Windows), the output from this is not reliable. The surefire way of getting the hashkey is by getting it from code. See the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app

Comment: i tried it but no hope to solve this issue. the problem may be in facebook SDk 3. and the most strange thing it runs fine in debug mode and when signed can not logged to facebook .

Comment: guys, it works fine on Android 4.0 but still does not work on Android 2.2 do have any idea why this issue?