# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 Session State "Opening"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am integrating Facebook's Login using their documentation. I am running into an issue where when i click the Facebook Login Widget the session changes to "Opening" and the app crashes

My Layout for Facebook button

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    />
```

The Fragment is

```
public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "FacebookFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
            (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
    else
        Log.i(TAG, session.toString());
}
```

}

and in the activity i have implemented the required onActivityResult and retrieving the fragment

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new FacebookFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (FacebookFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }   
}


    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I thought maybe the issue lies with the Key Hash, but i followed the directions completely from the answer posted on this question [Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Any lead on how to get the state to "Opened" would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in having android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" on the activity that was doing the facebook login. The OnActivityResult was not able to be called. I was able to get a Exception when i ran the application in debug mode.

Comment: +1 `android:noHistory="true"` in the `AndroidManifest` was the reason for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `session.addCallback(callback)` in your `onResume()`:

```
super.onResume();
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.addCallback(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go when I get to my computer

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but what is the purpose of the callback?

Comment: Callback is an interface with one abstract method (call), which is called each time the session changed state (Open, Closed, Openning, ...). You already implemented Session.Callback (callback) in your code. You need it to check when session has finally changed state to Open

Comment: i added the callback but the app still closes

Comment: Make sure you do not do anything with the session (query posts, comment, share, ...) untill it is open and that you have the correct permissions

Comment: In fact you don't need to add that code, it is already done by the `UILifecycleHelper onResume` method.