# android keyhash too big

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to find the keyhash from command prompt for my keystore file and its commming to big and I tried to paste it to the facebook's app dashboard. Then the dashboard is taking only upto few characters.

Is it write key it is taking or not my key hash is:

`MIICizCCAfSgAwIBAgIETe3Q4jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBiDELMAkGA1UEBhMC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`

and facebook is taking only first row. Is it a wrong key hash if yes what can be the reason?

got the key in correct format after editing(added) my path sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64..

Comment: i've created a tool for that, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.eatapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

and you will see the key hash on your logcat view certainly the key hash generated is incorrect