# Getting error message in facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, integration

I am working in facebook integration i have implement code from [android tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) ,its work fine for first time second time its showing error message

```
Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.
```

here is the error screen

[image]

could somebody tell me why is this happening, any idea..@Thanks

Comment: That tutorial is old, and probably uses deprecated versions of the SDK. Please follow the getting started guide and tutorials on the Facebook developers site - https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Comment: @MingLi thanks actually i tried that also but i can't solve this issue..i think its related to hashkey ..

Comment: There are many questions about the hash key on StackOverflow, using something outlined in this answer (the second one, where you log it from code) is probably your best bet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app But please use the newest version of the SDK, and follow the new tutorials. The one you linked uses a deprecated class which will no longer be supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you added this facebook user to Roles section, you have to confirm that request from that user account.