# Trying to get the key hash of my released key for facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get a key hash for facebook using my release key but the hash I get which I saved in facebook still gives me a invalid android_key parameter. I can't seem to figure out why.

I entered the right command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias my.keystore -
keystore "C:\Users\Gateway\School Work\My stuff\my.keystore" | "C:\Users
\Gateway\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\
Gateway\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
Enter keystore password:  
......
```

and everything worked, but the returned hash still doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [key hash for android-facebook app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Comment: That link doesn't answer my question. I checked it already.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the alias was wrong, so it gave me a wrong hash key.