# Release apk Facebook hash key not same with generated one

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-keystore

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am integrating Facebook Login. My Facebook login working fine. But not working when I produce release apk and run that app and try to log in with Facebook.

1. I generate release apk like below

[image]

[image]

2. Then I generate keyhash using that jks file path.
3. I got a hash key and then add it to the developer profile settings.

When I install and run that apk on my device and login using Facebook, it always shows error like below.

[image]

Facebook hash key misconfiguration. Actually all the steps I did was right. So what I tried is, I tried copy that hash key to developer settings and not working. I tried another way. I generated new release apk with new key (different jks file). Then I generated hash key for it and add it to developer settings. Then I run app on my phone and log in. It gives me same error. Besides, it shows the same error with same hash key even if I generated another release apk with different key. What is wrong?

### Update

All the release apk can login to Facebook at first time. Then log in again. Above error shows. Uninstall the app and install again not working. But if I generate a release apk with different keystore, it works for the first time, then not working. Uninstall and reinstall not working as well. What is the possible error?

Comment: Please look to this link it may help you [Facebook Login for Android App with release key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662606/7108113)

Comment: In my case it was actually problem with OpenSSL library for Windows 10.. check out this SO answer which solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612386/4513962

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem too... When you generate the hash key, you add your computer password, but you have to write `android`
You will get the key hash that facebook is showing you.

So, add it on your app on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/)

See it here how to do it: [android facebook integration invalid key hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash)

Comment: Yes, the second link has solution I used. Other solutions may also be useful if similar issue occured.

Comment: Hi, I have release the build apk with release key store and I am installing that in my phone. I have tried with face book login in my app it's showing invalid hash key error. When I  am adding that hash key in to my fb developer account it's working fine. I HAVE DOUBT ON IF THAT APK IS PUSH IN TO PLAY STORE IS FB LOGIN IS WORKING FINE OR ANY HASH KEY RELATED ISSUES WE ARE FACING?.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was generating the hash key in the terminal using my pc's password, but when I wrote "android", the correct hash key was returned 

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error is awkward. It should not happen because I properly followed the steps of generating hash key. I tried generate hash key many times to solve this error. No matter how I tried, hash key is always different in the release apk. Before I developed an app using the same way, it was working fine and now up and running.

I solved the problem. Hash key is always different no matter how I generated. How I solved was just copy the hash key in the error message and add it to the Facebook developer app settings. That's it.

Comment: Hi, I have release the build apk with release key store and I am installing that in my phone. I have tried with face book login in my app it's showing invalid hash key error. When I  am adding that hash key in to my fb developer account it's working fine. I HAVE DOUBT ON IF THAT APK IS PUSH IN TO PLAY STORE IS FB LOGIN IS WORKING FINE OR ANY HASH KEY RELATED ISSUES WE ARE FACING?.