# cocoonJS Facebook integration and hash key mismatch

Tags: android, facebook, hash, construct-2, cocoonjs

I am trying to integrate CocoonJS Social with my app. When I run it under their launcher it returns the following exception as a response from facebook ApiException: Key hash E7rnQv1gxeHDd0uOra-0EHzc1hE does not match any stored key hashes.

I took this hash key and placed it in my FB app and its not working.

I have other standalone applications working and used hash keys before (to run air applications).

also, how can i know the package name and class name of the ludei app launcher if this is required?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I realized that I had a wrong version of OpenSSL. If you are exporting the hash on a Windows 64bit computer, try using the following version of OpenSSL:

http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip&can=2&q=

This SO answer pointed me in the right direction:

[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Hope it helps!