# Facebook Android Key Hash

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-android-sdk, hashcode

I'm trying to generate key hash code for android on (Windows 8.1 PRO 64x) according to these steps [Android key hash for Facebook App](http://shareprob.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-key-hash-for-facebook-app-its.html). I did it before and worked well but was for windows 8, now I followed all the steps and the hash code I got was this.

[image: Imgur]

Any suggestions how to solve it or what is this ??

Comment: You can use my simple tool i created for windows.
check it out :[here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2476453

Comment: possible duplicate of [key hash for android-facebook app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your hash in a easier way, like in the offical Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

    ...
}
```