# Phonegap Facebook Dashboard Configuration

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am trying to handle Facebook connection with `phone-gap`. I get this error from Facebook: `given url is not allowed by the application configuration`.

I tried some solutions found on `stack-overflow` but I'm unable to make it work.

My application is including a plugin to handle `Facebook login`.

I already add an Android application in Facebook Dashboard with:

- (1)Package Name: com.example.app
- (2)Class Name: com.example.app.Phonegap
- (3)Key Hashes: myHash
- App Domains: empty
- Single Sign On: OK
- Deep Linking: KO
- (1) Found in my AndroidManifest.xml : package="com.example.app"
- (2) Found in my AndroidManifest.xml : android:name="Phonegap"
- (3) Using this command : 'keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64' according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Phonegap" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Am i using the right Package Name and Class Name or do I need to use the id of the plugin (from plugin.xml) I use to handle Facebook login?

Thanks for help!