# How to get Hash key for Facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, hashmap

I'm trying to obtain the key hash for integrating **facebook** into my **Android** app. But all over the net I can't find the way to do it on `MAC OS X`

Comment: check this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app