# cannot get android key hash for facebook app

Tags: android

when I run  keytool in cmd to generate a hash key for facebook api, I get this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Loay\Ravi\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base
64
'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have `openssl` installed

Comment: you can use my tools for mac and windows to generate keyhash here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember for the life of me where I got this from years ago to give proper credit, but why not have the app tell you:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void getApplicationSignature(Activity activity){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package.name.here", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

Just be sure to replace "your.package.name.here" with your root package name.

Edit: But if you want to go the openSSL route, TDMaster's answer about adding it to your Path variable is the solution you want. Just kinda thought I'd throw this one out there too.

Answer (score 0):

Add the OpenSSL Path to your computer Variables

[Instractions](http://pubs.vmware.com/view-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.view.installation.doc/GUID-9C91500B-2E8F-4707-9E61-0DC50CC4EE4A.html)

or copy the openssl to the same location of the keytool