# android facebook login is not working with native facebook installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my android app.
My app is not asking permissions with native facebook installed in my device.
But when i switched to web login interface, the login is working fine.
Is it common problem or I'm missing something..?

**SplashFragment.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {

private final String APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXX";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    //authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setApplicationId(APP_ID);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays
            .asList("read_stream", "basic_info","public_profile"));

    return view;
}
}
```

I'm using LoginActivity.java provided by facebook sdk.

Comment: did you generate hashkey and added in facebook app setting?

Comment: yes i've added one keyhash for debugger and one keyhash for production.

Comment: there may be something wrong in hashkey generation

Comment: you can use my tools for mac and windows to generate keyhash here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605

Comment: problem not resolved, i've done work around by forcing application to not use single-sign-on.

Answer (score 1):

When ever we try to generate hashkey with keytool(through command prompt) i am facing this issue.by generating hash key with code we can resolve this issue. sample code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Add code to print out the key hash

    try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

...
Reference link: 
[please check this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Answer (score -1):

To make facebook login working with native application you need to generate hashkey like this

**For Linux**

Open Terminal :

**For Debug Build**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

you wil find **debug.keystore** from ".android" folder copy it from and paste on desktop and run above command

**For release Build**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**NOTE : Make sure In Both case it must ask for password. If it does not asks for password that means something is wrong in command.**

**Where To set HashKey?**

1) Open facebook developer page

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

2) Follow the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I tried the two commands given by you. and they result in same hash keys that are generated earlier. do i need to remove debug key after i copied production key hash?

Comment: No no you can put multiple keyhash

Answer (score -1):

Use that method to generate the hash key .. the command line way always gave me wrong hashes

```
public static String getAppKeyHash(Context context) {
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.app", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        String hash = null;
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            hash = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.d("KeyHash:", hash);
        }
        return hash;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

replace com.example.app with your package name