# Cordova/PhoneGap: Package Name, Class Name, Key Hashes

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm adding a Facebook plugin to my Cordova app. And now trying to register the platform at https://developers.facebook.com/

It requires the following info from me:

- Package Name
- Class Name
- Key Hashes

Could someone tell me how I can find the package and class name, and how to generate the key hashes?

Mind you, I am using the **Cordova command line tool** and no editors.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here for hash key.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app

Comment: package and class name is the package in which your main android class resides (the one that extends DroidGap class), and class is that class name.

Comment: So the package name is the widget id "com.mydomain.demo" and class name is "demo"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this one

development mode

> keytool -exportcert -alias YourProjectName -keystore
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

password: **android**

production mode

> keytool -exportcert -alias YourProjectName -keystore
>   /Dekstop/YourProject/YourProject.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

password: yourKeyStorePassword

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/05/20/integration-cordova-facebook-connect-plugin-for-android/

Comment: for development mode, I had to use "androiddebugkey" as the alias