# Android, Facebook and key hashes, how does it work?

Tags: java, android, deployment, release, facebook-android-sdk

When releasing my first android app using the facebook sdk, what are all the steps involved to get it working? The process is confusing me, the Key Hashes in particular.

**1.** Take the **App ID** from my facebook App and put it into my **AndroidManifest.xml**

**2.** Add the platform: **Android** in the developers.facebook.com App-Settings

**3.** Copy my **Package Name** to the Android-form at developers.facebook.com

**4.** ?

EDIT:

By releasing an app to Google Play without facebook in it and then reading this:
[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

I learned everything I needed to know. I will answer my own post eventually with all the steps needed, if someone else don't beat me to it.

Comment: You will generate a release key when you sign your app. Then you will generate a new hash using that key.

Comment: @Emmanuel thanks, I will continue my quest to understand this process then..