# Generating release key hash in Linux OS(Ubuntu) : Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, hash, facebook-android-sdk

How can I generate the right release key hash in Ubuntu?
I have already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448684/android-facebook-sdk-generate-release-key-hash) but i can't get my answer.

Comment: The solution you refer to is exactly what you need. Were you able to run the command?

Comment: @Logain i got both solution which i looking for.Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After trying many time i got solution for `fragment` which give me a release key hash.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.yourappname.app",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash", "KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                    Base64.DEFAULT));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                    Base64.DEFAULT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

[image]

And i got this command  from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448684/android-facebook-sdk-generate-release-key-hash) for terminal which give me release key hash.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: `GET_SIGNATURES` is deprecated