# How can I get Access Token and other info correctly after logging in Facebook App and authorizing my app? [Android]

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I'm using [this](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidFacebook/). In my `Facebook.java` in my `authorized()` method I call `startSingleSignOn` and `startDialogAuth`, I'm using the `DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE` instead of `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH`

public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {

```
    boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;

    mAuthDialogListener = listener;

    // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
    if (activityCode >= 0) {
        singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                permissions, activityCode);
    }
    // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
    if (!singleSignOnStarted) {
        startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
    }
}
```

I noticed that in my `startDialogAuth` it sets the `AccessToken` and `AccessExpires`

```
private void startDialogAuth(Activity activity, String[] permissions) {

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    if (permissions.length > 0) {
        params.putString("scope", TextUtils.join(",", permissions));
    }
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity);
    dialog(activity, LOGIN, params, new DialogListener() {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            // ensure any cookies set by the dialog are saved
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            setAccessToken(values.getString(TOKEN));
            setAccessExpiresIn(values.getString(EXPIRES));
            if (isSessionValid()) {
                Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login Success! access_token="
                        + getAccessToken() + " expires="
                        + getAccessExpires());

                mAuthDialogListener.onComplete(values);
            } else {
                mAuthDialogListener.onFacebookError(new FacebookError(
                                "Failed to receive access token."));
            }
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login failed: " + error);
            mAuthDialogListener.onError(error);
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login failed: " + error);
            mAuthDialogListener.onFacebookError(error);
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            Util.logd("Facebook-authorize", "Login canceled");
            mAuthDialogListener.onCancel();
        }
    });
}
```

And in the `startSingleSignOn` it looks like this

```
private boolean startSingleSignOn(Activity activity, String applicationId,
        String[] permissions, int activityCode) {
    boolean didSucceed = true;
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
            "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");
    intent.putExtra("client_id", applicationId);

    if (permissions.length > 0) {
        intent.putExtra("scope", TextUtils.join(",", permissions));
    }

    // Verify that the application whose package name is
    // com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth
    // has the expected FB app signature.
    if (!validateActivityIntent(activity, intent)) {
        return false;
    }

    mAuthActivity = activity;
    mAuthPermissions = permissions;
    mAuthActivityCode = activityCode;

    try {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        didSucceed = false;
    }

    return didSucceed;
}
```

I'm wondering where it sets the `Access Token` that is needed when logs-in, I'm facing the problem where the user has a `Facebook app` installed and already authorized my app, it will only show a dialog (Loading) and display a white screen then dismiss but nothing happen next. It doesn't get the user's information from the logged `Facebook app`. But when the user doesn't have a `Facebook app` it displays the WebView and just working fine, it logs in correctly. While debugging it I also notice that it doesn't go inside my function `LoginDialogListener` here it implements `Facebook.DialogListener` (when there is facebook app installed) maybe because in `startSingleSignOn` it doesn't call `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity);
        dialog(activity, LOGIN, params, new DialogListener() {`

here's my `activity` code where it calls the `facebook.authorize`

```
public void setFacebookConnection() {
    facebook = new Facebook(Constants.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    facebookAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    facebook.authorize(this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
}

private class LoginDialogListener implements Facebook.DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LoginONComplete");
        String token = facebook.getAccessToken();
        long token_expires = facebook.getAccessExpires();
        Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
        Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);

        if (isPublishStreamAuthorized()) {
            facebookSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            facebookSharedPreferences
                    .edit()
                    .putLong(Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_EXPIRES,
                            token_expires).commit();
            facebookSharedPreferences.edit()
                    .putString(Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN, token)
                    .commit();
            facebookAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
        } else {
            logoutFacebook();
        }

    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCancel");
        logoutFacebook();
    }

}
```

It seems that my `facebook.getAccessToken();` in my activity returns null, as tried calling in my `setFacebookConnection()` after calling `facebook.authorize()`

Can you please help me? I needed to solve this soon. Thank you so much.

**Update**

I found  [this](http://ukgupta.blogspot.com/2011/07/facebook-implementation-into-android.html)  and tried doing step 3 but it ends up opening the `WebView` again.

***Update

I finally get the `access token`, by calling `onActivityResult()`  but the get data will only show after I close the app and open it again here is my code where `FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE` value I changed it to 32665.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE) {
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult Error : Authentication Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you referring is too old. Some of them might be deprecated. Try the official docs and examples https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: @MahendranSakkarai i need to use this to avoid big changes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gradle:

> ```
> compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
> ```

strings.xml

> ```
> <string name="facebook_app_id">YOUR_APP_ID</string>
> ```

AndroidManifest.xml
Add inside of 'application' tag:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Create this to init FacebookSDK:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

Add it to AndroidManifest.xml to 'application' tag as the name:

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApp"
```

In your activity layout add Facebook Login Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.FacebookLoginActivity">

 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your FacebookLoginActivity: And Here you can get now your Facebook Token.

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private String FB_TOKEN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            /**
             * HERE YOU CAN GET YOUR FACEBOOK TOKEN!!!!
             **/
            FB_TOKEN=loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

If you need to use Custom Facebook Button:

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private Button loginButton;
private String FB_TOKEN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    /**
                    * HERE YOU CAN GET YOUR FACEBOOK TOKEN!!!!
                    **/
                    FB_TOKEN=loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.e("onError", exception.getMessage());
                }
            });
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FacebookLoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
            }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

Comment: Using the above code, can I still check if the facebook app is installed and if not it will open a `WebView` instead?

Comment: also can i use my custom facebook button?

Comment: @mori Yep sure, i edited my answer. I Added example: how to use Custom Facebook Button.

Comment: @mori ask me if you have any questions =)

Comment: Thank you so much @Rahim , also how can i get the `token_expires` ?

Comment: i tried the code using the custom but it doesn't open the facebook app :(

Comment: 1) Reinstall your app and try again, 2)  Check again your facebook sdk id, 3) Go to developers.facebook.com and check the correctness of written Hash addresses and package name of your app. 4) Here is how to get correct Hash for facebook sdk: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35128380/4576879

Comment: Also provide me with Logs when you pressing that button.

Comment: @mori try loginResult.getAccessToken().getExpires() to get token_expires

Comment: it looks like I need to still used the old `Facebook.java`, I changed the `FACEBOOK_AUTH_RESULT_CODE` to other values and i can get the access token but it crashes after going back to my app. I still don't know the reason why it crashes.

Comment: U should use this one:  @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

Comment: don't forget that: minSdkVersion 15

Comment: if nothing helps i can help you with TeamVIewer

Comment: the `<provider>` tag should I add in inside the <application> ? In the Manifest?

Comment: is `FacebookLoginActivity` and `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` are different activity?

Comment: I can log-in now but I wonder how can I get the other info like gender, locale, verified and email?

Comment: i tried using the custom button but I'm having error `Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult`

Answer (score 1):

1)You don't need to use 'provider' tag.

2) com.facebook.FacebookActivity is Facebook's own activity, FacebookLoginActivity - yours.

3)Just use this code to get gender, locale, verified, email:

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                    JSONObject object,
                    GraphResponse response) {
            }
        });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,gender,verified,locale,email");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

4) Could you please share your class. I need more information about "Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult"

Comment: I fixed the `Unexpected call to LoginManager.onActivityResult` it is because of the intent I'm calling in my `onActivityResult` Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @natsumiyu can you post the code please - I have the same issue