# How to custom the style LoginButton of Facebook but still Logs in correctly

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using `Facebook SDK 4.16.1` I'm wondering instead of using the default style of facebook `login button` how will I customize its style? I wanted to use an icon instead of a long button or edit its text if I will use the long button . How to do this? I tried using like below in my `onCreate` but it doesn't work like how it should be, It goes to the `onActivityResult` but ignores my `FacebookCallback`. Maybe I should still use `<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>` but how will I change the style?

```
facebookButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFacebookLogin);
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    com.facebook.AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                    FB_TOKEN=loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

                    id = profile.getId();
            fname = profile.getFirstName();
            lname = profile.getLastName();
            name = profile.getName();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {


                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            response.getError();
                            Log.e("JSON-RESULT:", object.toString());

                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                try {
                                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(object.toString());
                                    email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                    gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                    locale = jsonObject.getString("locale");
                                    verified = jsonObject.getString("verified");

                                    Log.e(TAG, email + " This is the email");

                                    saveToDB();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,first_name,last_name,email,gender,verified,locale");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.e("onError", exception.getMessage());
                }
            });
    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SocialNetworkLoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList(Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS));
        }
    });
```

My `Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS` looks like this

```
public static final String[] FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
                                                                "public_profile",
                                                                "user_friends",
                                                                "email" };
```

My layout looks like this

```
  <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonFacebookLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_socialnetwork_facebook"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_facebook"
                android:src="@drawable/button_image_facebook" />
```

Comment: simply use a `Button` instead of `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`

Comment: Use your own button

Comment: I used my own `Button` / `ImageButton` like above, but it doesn't work. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the provided answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007474/how-can-i-get-access-token-and-other-info-correctly-after-logging-in-facebook-ap) By @Rahim Rahimov  on how to custom style the `LoginButton`. It is a great sample to use.

And check my `onActivityResult` I mistype my Intent. It's working fine now.