# Facebook analytics event logging not showing in event debugging

Tags: android, facebook-analytics

I'm trying to get an android app to log to facebook analytics, i've followed many different guides:

[Android quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/products/analytics/quickstarts/android/)

[quickstarts for a specific facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/)

[Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

And checked that my key hashes are correct with these:

[Generate debug key hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash)

[Generate release key hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448684/android-facebook-sdk-generate-release-key-hash)

How can i debug this? Do events from simulator show up in event debugging or do i have to release new versions to test this?

Maybe someone with experience could share what is most likely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have done all basic configuration like adding `appid` in Strings.xml `activity` declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`

So all you need to do is activate the `EventLogger` via `Application` class.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

 private static AppEventsLogger mLogger;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();    
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    public AppEventsLogger getAppLoggerInstance(){
        if(mLogger == null){
            return mLogger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(this);
        }
        return mLogger;
    }
}
```

And user your `AppEventLogger`instance in Activity like this :

```
private void logFbEvent(String mEventName ){
        AppEventsLogger mLogger = ((MyApp)getApplication()).getAppLoggerInstance();
        mLogger.logEvent(mEventName);
    }
```

PS :
`Application` class has to be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this

```
<application
        android:name=".QTConnectApp"
  ....
```