# Generating Facebook release key hash

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an app that contains a "share to facebook"-button, and am about to publish it soon. To do that, I know I need to add a release key hash in my app's settings in the facebook developer console. Following the steps in facebook's developer documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#release-key-hash), they say:

> When publishing your app, it is typically signed with a different signature to your development environment. Therefore, you want to make sure you create a Release Key Hash and add this to the Android settings for Facebook App ID.

And then, also as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448684/android-facebook-sdk-generate-release-key-hash), facebook want me to run the following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl base64
```

Does this mean I should sign my release build **before** following facebook's guide in order to get this release key path?

What is release key alias, is it just a name that is only used here or do it need to match something else I've entered somewhere?

What is "Class Name" that they want me to enter in the facebook settings. Is it the name of the activity which will launch the share-to-facebook intent? The tip says "The Main Activity you want Facebook to launch". How should I know what their activity is called? I don't want Facebook to launch one of my activities, I want to launch one of theirs...

How can I confirm that it works once I've set a valid release key hash in facebook developer settings?

Comment: Easiest way will be , generate signed apk . Install it on your phone , make sure your phone has facebook app . try to login with facebook in your app . with it throw an error that hash key does not match . just copy the key now shown in facebook app

Answer (score 2):

> What is release key alias, is it just a name that is only used here or do it need to match something else I've entered somewhere?

**RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS** - > alias name in the keystore(.jks) which used to sign the apk

> Does this mean I should sign my release build before following facebook's guide in order to get this release key path?

**RELEASE_KEY_PATH** -> path to the keystore(.jks) file which used to sign the apk

You can find complete step to step guide over here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241386/6478047

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am getting confused since the link you provided suggests to use debug.keystore and androiddebugkey as alias. Why should I do this when I want a release key hash?

Comment: That is for debug for release , change path in step 5  to your .jks file location and alias to the alias you gave while creating .jks file

Comment: Final command will be something like 

`keytool -exportcert -alias xyzalias -keystore "E:\KeyStore\xyzproject.jks"  | "C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" base64`

Comment: @ManoharReddy I followed exactly what you told but still no success

Comment: @ManoharReddy: Please Check issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229354/cannot-generate-correct-facebook-key-hash-for-release-apk

Answer (score 1):

1. download "openssl" for windows in zip

https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/files/latest/download

2. extract zip in the path you want.
3. get path for "bin" folder.
4. write the path string

That's it