# Android Key Hash for Facebook with Cordova

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, meteor

I'm developing a hybrid app with Meteor and Cordova. I'm trying to configure Facebook Connect and got it working on iOS but I'm stuck on android. I cannot seem to find the correct key hash.
I always get the message:

> Invalid key hash. The key hash ... does not match any stored key hashes.

I already tried to find the correct key hash via the following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and the standard password "android". I added the resulting key to Facebook but it didn't help. I also tried the tool in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app). It gave me another key which also did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meteor uses its own debug keystore when creating an android app via *meteor run android-device*.
The keystore can be found at *~/.meteor/android_bundle/.android/debug.keystore*.

Use the following code and the keystore password *android* for creating your keyhash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore \
~/.meteor/android_bundle/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem and simply had to put the key which was on the error message on FB settings. It worked.

Comment: It's not easy to tell apart some characters in that message, such as `L / I, O / 0.` It's not an option to try all combinations.

Comment: There is no way to copy/paste from within the native flow. That's the reason for this question in the first place.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. In the windows cmd line or linux you get the error and you just haev to copy paste the key

Answer (score -1):

> Facebook keyhash works with your application's package name and keystore.

Get your apk signed with a production keystore and use below code to get the facbook keyhash

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

The facebook Keyhash wil start with **'=' equals to sign.** For testing purpose you can have both keyhash from debug keystore as well as production keystore.

More information is available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started).

Comment: I'm creating a cordova app like I said, so I wouldn't really know where to put your proposed Java code. There has to be a solution without using custom code?

Comment: The post clearly states that it's a Cordova question, downvoted for not explaining how to put this in a Cordova project, although the code snippet actually worked.