# Facebook Key hash is not generating

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have to use login with Facebook functionality in my android application. For this I need to generate key hash. I am using following code to generate facebook key hash.

```
public class GenerateFacebookSignature extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        printHashKey();
    }

    public void printHashKey() {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.facebooklogin", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
                MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                messageDigest.update(signature.toByteArray());

                Log.d("FaceBookKeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(messageDigest.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

This class is under a different package named `com.example.facebooklogin.application` while my other application classes are in the package `com.example.facebooklogin`.

I have included this in my manifest.xml file but it is not showing any hash key in logcat.

```
<application
        android:name=".application.GenerateFacebookSignature">
</application>
```

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app/17732453#17732453

Answer (score 2):

It is raising an exception, because it can't find `"com.example.facebooklogin"`.

Change it to your package name and it should work. You can use `Context#getPackageName()` like so:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
```

Comment: But it is not showing any exception means application is running well.

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions by not printing anything in the logcat. Use `e.printStackTrace()` inside `catch` clauses.

Comment: i have e.printStackTrace() but it is running well till.

Comment: i have used getPackageName() also but no key hash would be generated.

Comment: @AshishKumarGupta, alright, add a different `Log.d()` message inside each piece of your code: `onCreate`, `printHashKey`, `try`, the `for` loop, both `catch`. This way you can see what gets executed and what's not executed and report back. You can also do the same thing with a debugger.

Comment: Now i am having a facebook connect button in my activity on whose click i want the user to got login with facebook. Whereas facebook documentation is giving a default button for login purpose. Which activity i would call to login my user on my own button click.

Comment: @AshishKumarGupta, post a separate question and someone will help you.