# Facebook Invalid Key Hash for any application

Tags: facebook, hash

i have one problem.
I try to connect the navigation application named : Waze, and when i wanted to connect with facebook account, i have this following error message :

"Invalid key hash. They key hash ..... does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/343050668156".
I went to this website but i found nothing.

i try to search in different question here but all i found, its people creating their own application. And i didn't create this application. I just want to connect with my facebook.
[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how're you connecting to Waze?

Comment: I find it , my token as expired, i have to delete Wazer in my facebook application and its good. Wazer create a new token for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to delete the application on Facebook , and reconnect with this application, he will create me a new token and new key hash.