# Facebook KeyHash for Signed APK

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

My Android app has a Facebook login feature. For debug I was generating keyhash using method defined on Facebook developer console. For signed APK I have to create new signed key using open SSL. I tried download OpenSSL from [here](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list)
but after extracting bin folder does not contain debug.text file.

When I run the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore F:\signed\debug.keystore > E:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
```

It says command not available.

Please suggest how I can generate a keyhash for signed apk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is using the debug key, and not your release key: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey...`. Also, put your Java and Android tools on path.

Comment: @jww can you please explain how can I do that.I am struggling on it.

Comment: any one have idea what issue in my steps?

Comment: you can use a tool that i built for ios and windows, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605 and update my answer there if that helped you. Thanks