# How does Ionic/Cordova generate hash key?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-facebook

I'm working on adding Facebook API integration with ionic/Cordova and am trying to find the debug hash key that is generated for my app when I do:

```
ionic build android
```

I know that it generates a new .keystore file at /userhomedir/.android/debug.keystore. But **what does it set as the alias and password**? And how can I retrieve this hash key after Cordova has created it for my app. I don't see the hash key being printed anywhere during the build process.

I need the generated hash key to give to Facebook API to use their sign on SDK

Comment: I'm having the same problem, im frustrated theres not enough documentation for this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems Cordova use `~/android/debug.keystore` with the password `android`

To get it :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

With `password : android`

Comment: this command is for ubuntu. change `~/` to the user root path of your os

Comment: What path does ~/android/debug.keystore refer to in windows ? Any body knows this?

Answer (score 19):

One answer that worked for me is this [one](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/key-hash-for-facebook-not-working/44357/5?u=momar):

- Copy the `apkname.apk` file you want to know the hash of to the '*Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin*' folder
- Run this command `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile apkname.apk`
- Copy the `SHA1` value and convert it using this [site](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)
- Use the converted Keyhash value (*ex. zaHqo1xcaPv6CmvlWnJk3SaNRIQ=*)

Answer (score -1):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

Comment: Could you add a few words to help explain your answer?