# Use an unlimited hash key Android (Ionic 3)

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm creating my app with Ionic 3 and I set up a connection via facebook, but after generating my hash key and after the build, I can connect only once to Facebook..

After this, I have this message :

> Invalid key hash. The key hash ..... dos not match any stored key
>   hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.../dashboard/

My steps :

- Create Facebook app
- Add Android platform
- Add the Build ID
- Run the command :

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

- Add Key Hash
- Run the command :

> ionic build android

I can only log in once, after my key hash is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Catch and Log de Exception thrown by the plugin , it will have a Key Hash, you paste that on the Facebook Developers project console. I'm not really sure why the key hash in the environment differs from the one used on compilation.

Edit: I found something, check this out [How does Ionic/Cordova generate hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915985/how-does-ionic-cordova-generate-hash-key)