# Android: How to get Release Key Hash for facebook for SIGNED app NOT Debug mode

Tags: android, facebook

i integrated facebook sdk to my app and all thing is ok in debug mode i could login and get all data from facebook in debug mode but in signed mode i couldnt find the new hashkey , i followed many tutorials but i didnot find the answer 
 these are metheds i followed:

```
1-try
    {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.Rapp.app", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {

    }


 2-
       keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore              
      ~/.android/signedkey.keystore > key.out
       cat key.out | openssl sha1 -binary > key.bin
       cat key.bin | openssl base64
```

Comment: When you sign your apk, you have the release keystore which can help you get the release key (hash) to add to your Facebook Developer account. Have you submitted your app for review on Facebook?

Comment: @Eenvincible i have not submit it to facebook !! what is the relation to get signed hash key ?

Comment: Well, first, if you don't submit, your facebook features won't work when you publish the app

Comment: Check out my automatic tool here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605. generate a release keystore and drop it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the jks file, then execute this command :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

where:

`YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH` : PATH to your .jks file

and

`YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS` : ALIAS NAME you used for making the release APK.