# How to manage a hash key in facebook for android app?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am integrating my android app with Facebook using Facebook SDK.

I have two question.
1. Do I have to generate hash key for each of the app that I'll develop?
2. Is there any debug hash key and release hash key?
Note : I'm not using Facebook login, just sharing to Facebook and messenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need a hash key for each of your apps when playing with Facebook. You can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14332237/1129332) to find your key.

Then fallow the official Facebook tutorial for [sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Please, do me another favor.
Is there any debug key release key?

Comment: @MisbahAhmad to get the debug key, just run the app in debug in see in the log your hash key, you can add many hashes to one facebook app, so you can add both production and debug hash