# Deep linking from Facebook Ad to 3rd party app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, deep-linking

I'm trying to setup deep links from a Facebook Ad to an app that I do not own (Shopee). Shopee does not provide any facility/guides to deep-link to them at the moment. I've tested that the app has properly setup deep linking on Android, i.e. clicking the link `https://shopee.ph/Korean-Mini-Cute-Sling-Bag-i.30650129.2385916193` on Slack or Gmail properly opens the Shopee app.

Is it possible to make deep links work on Facebook for apps that you do not own? So far, I've tried doing the steps detailed in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking/. However, I don't know where to get some of the platform settings needed by Facebook:

**iOS**

1. Bundle ID - where can I get this?
2. iPhone Store ID - Seems this can be easily taken when visiting the app store. I can get some of the details from https://shopee.ph/apple-app-site-association as well.
3. iPad Store ID - Similar to iPhone Store ID I guess.
4. Shared Secret - I'm someone who has no experience with iOS and Android programming. I'm afraid this setting is something that I couldn't get?

**Android**

1. Google Play Package Name - Should be `com.shopee.ph`
2. Class Name - I think this can be known by going through the app's apk/files
3. Key Hashes - Can this be taken from the app's apk/files as well?

I tried compromising by linking the Facebook ad to my website that has deeplinks. But clicking the links will just redirect Facebook's webview to the product's web info rather than opening the app.

I guess this question boils down to whether it's possible to get the app's **Shared Secret** for iOS and the **Key Hashes** for Android.

Any response will help me go to the right path or end the path altogether. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but if you don't own the app then you shouldn't possess shared secret and key hash of the app.

**Shared Secret**  and **Key hashes** both are something that is very specific to the app created. It is mostly controlled by the app owner in case you need it you have to get that transferred from the app owner. But I doubt anybody will do that.

Also, this is some kind of hack that you are doing this should be definitely avoided without permission from the app owner.

If you are the owner then for 
- Android you can try this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Android Intents? They can directly link to an app (including deeplink information). Of course you wouldn't now if its installed through adds beforehand. Firebase Dynamic Links solves that problem where you can decide to link to website or Play/App Store as fallback. They also open the native app from facebook browser (and others) and use Android Intents under the hood. 
Think you can't use Firebase Dynamic Links for an app you don't own. But if redirecting to your own website is an option maybe you can implement a similar mechanic.

Here is the chrome documentation for Android Intents: 
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Adjust also has a summary article about deep linking, covering Intents and iOS:
https://www.adjust.com/blog/dive-into-deeplinking/

Answer (score 0):

As your expected behavior to open app but now it will just redirect Facebook's web view to the product's web. Unfortunately it is not currently possible to directly launch a third-party app from within the iOS Facebook app. [This is a known issue that Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1640178609532119/) has essentially written off as wontfix. This is still possible in the Android Facebook app, but it's unfortunate they haven't been more transparent about the change to the iOS version because there is quite a bit of confusion about it.

But you cna do the same thing using services like **Branch.io** get around this by implementing a judicious combination of App Links, URI schemes, and iOS Universal Links. Essentially what you need to do is open a page in the webview and then have a button or other user-driven CTA event that launches the app from there. It's an extra step for the user, but currently the best workaround. If you just want to be able to post a link that goes into your app when it is installed and otherwise goes to a webpage (or the App/Play Store), then Branch links are definitely your simplest solution.